# How to Include Elastic IP on EC2 on my VPN

Tags: openvpn, aws-ec2, aws-vpc

I am able to ping and access SSH on my EC2 using Private IPs.

However I want to access the SSH using the Public IP ( elastic IP ).
Is that possible?

note: my VPN step up and EC2 is under 1 VPC

I have already added the Public IP to VPN Authorization and Security Group

Comment: Security Group

Enable SSH with the CIDR range of my VPC(Which solved the issue on SSH via Private IP)

On the Authorization Rule the elastic ID is already added.

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible since EIP runs on IGW